# Accessing and displaying certain xml elements from a Service Reference

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

I'm writing a Stock Quote app in Silverlight and I can't figure out how to display only the information that I want from the xml, such as the price of the stock. It will display the tags and everything.

Here is my code:

```
private void getQuote_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool check = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        if (check)
        {
            //available
            GetQuote.StockQuoteSoapClient client = new StockQuoteSoapClient();

            //call that method
            client.GetQuoteAsync(symbolBox.Text);




            //event handler response
            client.GetQuoteCompleted +=client_GetQuoteCompleted;

        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }

    public void client_GetQuoteCompleted(object sender, GetQuoteCompletedEventArgs e)
    {


        result.Text = e.Result;
  }
```

And here is the xml being returned by http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote

```
<string><StockQuotes><Stock><Symbol>msft</Symbol><Last>46.62</Last><Date>7/17/2015</Date><Time>4:00pm</Time><Change>-0.04</Change><Open>46.59</Open><High>46.78</High><Low>46.26</Low><Volume>29467107</Volume><MktCap>377.14B</MktCap><PreviousClose>46.66</PreviousClose><PercentageChange>-0.09%</PercentageChange><AnnRange>40.12 - 50.05</AnnRange><Earns>2.41</Earns><P-E>19.35</P-E><Name>Microsoft Corporation</Name></Stock></StockQuotes></string>
```

This is for a mobile app; it has to provide new, up-to-date information from the web service every time it is used, and I only need a few different pieces of the information. Also, the information shouldn't be specifically Microsoft, but any real company whose stock symbol is entered by the user.

Comment: Look into [LINQ-to-XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Comment: What does the xml look like that is returned?

Comment: Like this:     <string><StockQuotes><Stock><Symbol>msft</Symbol><Last>46.62</Last><Date>7/17/2015</Date><Time>4:00pm</Time><Change>-0.04</Change><Open>46.59</Open><High>46.78</High><Low>46.26</Low><Volume>29467107</Volume><MktCap>377.14B</MktCap><PreviousClose>46.66</PreviousClose><PercentageChange>-0.09%</PercentageChange><AnnRange>40.12 - 50.05</AnnRange><Earns>2.41</Earns><P-E>19.35</P-E><Name>Microsoft Corporation</Name></Stock></StockQuotes></string>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that XML sample, properly formatted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<string>" +
                 "<StockQuotes>" +
                   "<Stock>" +
                     "<Symbol>msft</Symbol>" +
                     "<Last>46.62</Last>" +
                     "<Date>7/17/2015</Date>" +
                     "<Time>4:00pm</Time>" +
                     "<Change>-0.04</Change>" +
                     "<Open>46.59</Open>" +
                     "<High>46.78</High>" +
                     "<Low>46.26</Low>" +
                     "<Volume>29467107</Volume>" +
                     "<MktCap>377.14B</MktCap>" +
                     "<PreviousClose>46.66</PreviousClose>" +
                     "<PercentageChange>-0.09%</PercentageChange>" +
                     "<AnnRange>40.12 - 50.05</AnnRange>" +
                     "<Earns>2.41</Earns>" +
                     "<P-E>19.35</P-E>" +
                     "<Name>Microsoft Corporation</Name>" +
                   "</Stock>" +
                 "</StockQuotes>" +
                "</string>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            var stocks = doc.Descendants("Stock").Select(x => new {
               symbol = x.Element("Symbol").Value,
               last = double.Parse(x.Element("Last").Value),
               date = DateTime.Parse(x.Element("Date").Value),
               time = DateTime.Parse(x.Element("Time").Value),
               change = double.Parse(x.Element("Change").Value),
               open = double.Parse(x.Element("Open").Value),
               high = double.Parse(x.Element("High").Value),
               low = double.Parse(x.Element("Low").Value),
               volume = long.Parse(x.Element("Volume").Value),
               mktcap = double.Parse(x.Element("MktCap").Value.Replace("B", "")),
               previousClose = double.Parse(x.Element("PreviousClose").Value),
               percentChange = double.Parse(x.Element("PercentageChange").Value.Replace("%", "")),
               annRange = x.Element("AnnRange").Value,
               earns = double.Parse(x.Element("Earns").Value),
               p_e = double.Parse(x.Element("P-E").Value),
               name = x.Element("Name").Value,
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: My fault, I should have specified: This is for a mobile app; it has to provide new, up-to-date information from the web service every time it is used, and I only need a few different pieces of the information. Also, the information shouldn't be specifically Microsoft, but any real company whose stock symbol is entered by the user.

Comment: Solution will get all stocks. The code creates an array or tags "Stock".  Doesn't matter if it contains one stock or many stocks.  You can remove any lines you don't need.  Because I'm using XDocument you need the xml identification line and you also need to one root tag (ie string) and its closing tag.  The root tag name is ignored so it can be anything.  And since I'm using Descendants() it doesn't matter how many levels deep the "Stock" tag is found.